# Closure properties of models of synthetic domain theory

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, domain-theory

I would like to know what topos models of synthetic domain theory are closed under. Here are some questions that I would be interested in an answer to:

1. Suppose $\mathbf{E}$ is an SDT-topos, and let $\mathbb{C}$ be an internal category in $\mathbf{E}$. Is the internal presheaf topos $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}\to \mathbf{E}$ an SDT-topos?
2. If $\mathbf{E}$ is an SDT-topos and $\mathbf{F}\subseteq\mathbf{E}$ is a sheaf subtopos of $\mathbf{E}$, is $\mathbf{F}$ an SDT-topos?
3. If $\mathbf{E}$ is an SDT topos, can the SDT structure be lifted along a product projection $\mathbf{F}\times\mathbf{E}\to\mathbf{E}$? (Here I am really talking about the cartesian product of topoi, not of categories.) Or can it be done under some additional assumptions, such as $\mathbf{F}$ being local, etc...

Right now I am more interested in Grothendieck topos models of SDT than the conventional realizability models. But I would be interested to hear about either.

Comment: I presume you are using geometric morphisms? Are they bounded by default?

Comment: Ah yes, let me assume bounded geometric morphisms. Thanks for asking!